# why rust macros have the same behavior with whatever delimiter?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

It's just curiosity, I noted that macros have the same behavior independently the delimiter with we call the macro, for example `println!(....)` have same behavior of `println!{....}` or `println![....]`.

Is this in fact so, or is it nuanced? and Exists any formal explanation for this?

Answer (score 0):

They're largely identical. You usually choose one that fits the scenario; if you're using a function-like macro (e.g. `println!`) you'd use parentheses, an array-like macro (e.g. `vec!`) you'd use square brackets, and use curly braces when it forms a logical block.

To my knowledge, the only difference between them is that curly braces (`{}`) are recognized as a block, so when you use them, you don't need to put a `;` at the end to make it a valid statement, where you would need to do so if you used `()` or `[]`.